# Bus pirate interface with with winbond chip

Tags: spi

I have successfully interfaced to my winbond chip via the bus pirate. 
I have successfully executed the chip identifier command and chip erase commands via spi, i would like to  read and delete the chips security registers.

This is the command set i push via spi with bus pirate for read:
datasheet: The instructions is initiated by driving the /CS pin low and then shifting the instruction code "48h" followed bya a 24-bit address(A23-A0) and eight "dummy clocks into the DI pin.

What i send:
[0x48 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 r:256] <-  read security register(read 256 bytes)

Each security register is 256 bytes in size and there are aparrantly 4 though i can only see 3 in the datasheet.

My questions is how would i read each security register 256 bytes at a time?

Section 8.2.33 is the reference and the the datasheet is here
http://www.nexflash.com/NR/rdonlyres/A5B6C30B-C174-43CF-867E-E1A2F371A07C/0/W25Q128FV.pdf

Comment: [0x48 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 r:256] should be [0x48 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 r:256] ? Because there are 24 bits address (3 bytes) + 8 dummy bits (1 byte) = 4 bytes?

Comment: sounds correct. how would i address each register?               [0x48 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 r:256] -<register 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the datasheet, the 3 security registers' address range are:

Security Register 1 (256 Bytes): 0x001000 ~ 0x0010FE

Security Register 2 (256 Bytes): 0x002000 ~ 0x0020FE

Security Register 3 (256 Bytes): 0x003000 ~ 0x0030FE

So, read 256 bytes from one register (read entire register) with Pirate bus SPI command, should be like

read Security Register 1 ==> [0x48 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x00 r r:255 ]

Comment: what does it mean followed by 8 dummy clocks to the di pin?

Comment: "Dummy" clocks means these clocks won't clock in/out useful data, the internal implementation of the chip may need these clocks to do some "preparation" before it can give you useful data.

Comment: ok so do i need to add these dummy clocks to the spi command? it does say instruction 48h followed by a 24bit address and eight dummy clocks into the di pin... how would i achieve this? really appreciate your help

Comment: You simply send the 3 bytes address, and then followed by 1 byte data (any is ok), and read.